# Tweepy Tweet Extraction

Tags: twitter, tweepy, keyword, tweets

Please share a full working code to extract tweets using Tweepy you can leave the place of consumer keys blank. Moreover, I need to search tweets using multiple keywords and boolean operators, like each tweet mentions Switzerland and one of the many keywords.
Switzerland AND (study OR education OR employment)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not a place to ask people to code on your behalf.

You can find a good starting point for your question in [the Tweepy examples](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/examples.html):

```py
import tweepy

bearer_token = ""

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token)

# Search Recent Tweets

# This endpoint/method returns Tweets from the last seven days

response = client.search_recent_tweets("Tweepy")
# The method returns a Response object, a named tuple with data, includes,
# errors, and meta fields
print(response.meta)

# In this case, the data field of the Response returned is a list of Tweet
# objects
tweets = response.data

# Each Tweet object has default ID and text fields
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.text)

# By default, this endpoint/method returns 10 results
# You can retrieve up to 100 Tweets by specifying max_results
response = client.search_recent_tweets("Tweepy", max_results=100)
```

You can adapt it with your query: `Switzerland (study OR education OR employment)`

You will find more details about the `search_recent_tweets` in [the Tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.search_recent_tweets).

And finally, if you need help building the query, you can read [the Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/build-a-query).